# What is the use of Javaaccessbridge.dll?

Tags: java

I am try to understand the JAB ,what is the use of the Javaaccessbridge.dll. I do understnad it use for
Inter process communication between Javaaccessbridge.dll and windowaccessbridge.dll.
I wants understand the internal mechenisum .like what the use of run API.
Can any one suggest the document for the same?

Answer (score 0):

@mahen this page has a  to the point explanation on why you will need the file.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/introduction.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks krishna ,i wants the api infomation which use by javaaccessbridge.dll.i already go through this document.

Comment: https://forio.com/epicenter/docs/public/api_adapters/generated/run-api-service/  Try this. The internal mechanism can be understood if you have a idea of run manager , filter() and query()methods.

Comment: Ok,i want to know how the run api connect with Jvm for javaaccessbridge.dll